# angular 4 cannot accept route having query parameter with reset token (%23 type value)

Tags: angular, angular4-router

i am try to navigate to email confirmation link. but angular 4 is not accepting followng url

```
RouterModule.forRoot([

        { path: "confirm/email/:token", component: EmailVerificationComponent, data: { title: "Email Confirmation" } }

    ])
```

---

componenet

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.token = params['token'];});
```

query string :
http://localhost:20179/confirm/email/CfDJ8MzNxfUhzJpLtzBSEMCaR%2FC%2BvVrueRghVTIdYmwt3AIHzKqMUwxq%2Flh2lhmcNPcH31SiDqWkzw4v5jgLbjL1p2SyPw2rfXIrMN2k4WzNk4TBTSB8h9PhjQRsThgwAMNH2bfUYqfUpckvzSc2F94Gg%2BFGZK8ZZnibGOBVFBwXm5SlB%2FN5oHdQgczEMvObNznt4msZK8QF8fj7hlJvXpNeM2nTpOhyiI5e4MfAZqxg2JbtOmMYE%2FYQMiwqsu6a3D6f4A%3D%3D

[image]

Comment: it navigate to not found url

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: @e.m.b it just navigate to `localhost:20179/` and doen't show any error

Comment: Check the web developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data` from your route definition and change it into following.

```
{path: "confirm/email/:token", component: EmailVerificationComponent}
```

Hope this helps.

I believe we don't have the role of `data` field while defining routes. We pass `data` when we are navigating between routes.

But for your use case, simply omitting `data` field from the route definition should work.

Comment: i just removed `data` from route definition 

angular routing doesn't accept parameter value. if i limit it to **50** it works but when query string has 275 characters it doen't work ..
it navigate to `localhost:20179/`

Comment: @TanveerHussain I'm not entirely sure on this but while receiving required routing parameters, I get it from `paramMap`. Try getting token from activated route snapshot's `paramMap` like this: `this.token = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('token')`. Maybe this helps.